# Tomcat App doesn't release cache

Tags: java, tomcat, caching

We've a tomcat application hosted in AWS cloud. I found something strange when I analysed the memory trends of application server for last one month. Our server has total 15GB RAM and 7GB is assigned for HeapSize. I noticed in monitoring system that memory utilization was reporting high. When I digged deep I found that memory used  is calculation includes (mem_used= cache memory+shared memory+buffer memory), We do tomcat reboot everyday but when I did full system reboot, I noticed that RAM utilization came down because system reboot dropped the cache. Now, the part which is puzzling me is that tomcat stop/start should release all the allocated memory by JVM, then why was the cache got release only by whole system reboot. Does tomcat doesn't flush the cache after we bounce it.

Answer (score 0):

Because the cache you are looking at, is the cache of the OS not Tomcat. Everything your Tomcat application reads on the file system will be cached by the operating system as long there is sufficient RAM.

For example the contents of the `servlet-api.jar` of your Tomcat installation might be cached. For the OS level cache this information is just blocks or pages. Every block that is requested quite often will stay in the cache, if the RAM is sufficient.

The OS is not clearing this information after Tomcat is stopped, because the cache should benefit the startup also. E.g. the JVM executables won't be read from disk again if you do a restart.

Comment: Yep. What good is having 15GiB of RAM when half of it isn't being used. You "pay" for it (in terms of power and OS mapping overhead) whether it's in-use or not, so you may as well use as much as possible. A server with a huge amount of "free" memory is hideously over-provisioned by definition.